# Push to observable array with concrete object or not?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

How is this:

```
var Tag = function (data) {
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
}

//////

self.tags.push(new Tag({name: self.newTagName()}));
```

different from just this:

```
self.tags.push({name: self.newTagName()});
```

I picked up the first form a tutorial and I start learning knockout, but it confused me, and I have tracked down the logic to the second option.

What are the pros for the first one?

Comment: Both are different you can see the difference in the sample here http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/X3NWm/37/ . cheers

Comment: It'd help if you also posted the `newTagName` function or observable, as well as some context as to what `self` is in this context.

Comment: @e4rthdog, could you leave me a comment with why my answer is 'less complete' (you changed the accepted answer) or  'less suited'. I don't mind but I can use feedback. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Both are same when coming to the pushing part but there is a big difference between both as you are pushing a `observable` in Case-1 were as in other case you trying to assign a value to `name` .

Performance perspective i don't think it makes a difference . Case-1 is readable and maintainable .

**View :**

```
Type 1: Not a observable (Two way binding doesn't exist)
<div data-bind="foreach:tags1">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value:name" />
</div>

Type 2:  Observable ( Two way binding )
<div data-bind="foreach:tags2">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value:name" />
</div>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
var vm =  function(){
var self=this;
self.tags1=ko.observableArray();
self.newTagName=ko.observable('Hi there');
self.tags1.push({name: self.newTagName()}); //you just pushing plane text

var Tag = function (data) {
 this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
}

self.tags2=ko.observableArray();
self.tags2.push(new Tag({name: self.newTagName()}));    
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

Working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/X3NWm/37/)**

Quick fix to make first case to work do something like this `self.tags1.push({name: ko.observable(self.newTagName())})`

Comment: I fail to grasp how Tag "observes" it self :) can you elaborate in dummy-person level?

Comment: sure let me try . see tag is just a normal function with observable `name` inside it . Here in `push(new Tag(` you just using instance of function to access the `name` and assigning the value to it (assigning to observable) . once you bind the assigned observable to view TWO WAY binding will be intact as it is observable(view & viewmodel in sync) .Here there is no black magic if you are aware c# classes , objects ,instances . Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Basically **you would use observables only when the state of the viewmodel property is dynamic, and changes in response to user 'input' (events)**. For example, if you had a list toolbar with up, down, add and remove buttons, you could have the following JS in your viewmodel:

```
this.toolbar = [
  {name: 'add', action: this.add, icon: 'plus'},
  {name: 'remove', action: this.remove, icon: 'close'},
  {name: 'up', action: this.moveUp, icon: 'arrow-up'},
  {name: 'down', action: this.moveUp, icon: 'arrow-down'}
];
```

And the following HTML:

```
<span data-bind="foreach: toolbar">
  <button type="button" data-bind="attr: { title: name }, click: action">
    <i data-bind="attr: { class: 'fa fa-' + icon}"></i>
  </button> 
</span>
```

IE the previous UI requires only one-way binding (model=>view); the buttons will not change.
However, suppose we would add a button to open/ close the details of each list item. This button has a **state**: open or closed. For this purpose we need to add an observable which holds a boolean in the button object. We also want to change the icon from + to -, and vice-versa on open/close, so 'icon' will be a computed property here, like so:

```
var toggleButton = {name: 'toggle'};
toggleButton.state = ko.observable(false); // closed by default
toggleButton.action = function() { toggleButton.state(!toggleButton.state()); };
toggleButton.icon = ko.computed(function() {
    return toggleButton.state() ? 'minus' : 'plus';});
this.toolbar.push(toggleButton);
```

And the modified HTML:

```
<span data-bind="foreach: toolbar">
  <button type="button" data-bind="attr: { title: name }, click: action">
    <i data-bind="attr: { class: 'fa fa-' + ko.unwrap(icon) }"></i>
  </button> 
</span>
```

As for the "what are the pros of regular objects/properties": they are static, so you would use them eg, for a unique "ID" property which never changes after creation. Performance-wise I have had some trouble only when an observable array contains many many items with many many observable properties.

Using constructor functions is handy (vs object literals) when your objects need their own scope, or if you have many of them to share prototype methods, or even, to automate JSON data mapping.

```js
var app = function() {
    this.add = this.remove = this.moveUp = this.moveDown = function dummy() { return; };
    this.toolbar = [
      {name: 'add', action: this.add, icon: 'plus'},
      {name: 'remove', action: this.remove, icon: 'close'},
      {name: 'up', action: this.moveUp, icon: 'arrow-up'},
      {name: 'down', action: this.moveUp, icon: 'arrow-down'}
    ];
    var toggleButton = {name: 'toggle'};
    toggleButton.state = ko.observable(false); // closed by default
    toggleButton.action = function() { toggleButton.state(!toggleButton.state()); };
    toggleButton.icon = ko.computed(function() { return toggleButton.state() ? 'minus' : 'plus';});
    this.toolbar.push(toggleButton);
}
ko.applyBindings(new app());
```

```css
.closed { overflow: hidden; left: -2000px; }
.open { left: 0; }
div { transition: .3s all ease-in-out; position: relative;}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<i>( only the last (toggle) button working for demo )</i>
<span data-bind="foreach: toolbar">
      <button type="button" data-bind="attr: { title: name }, click: action">
        <i data-bind="attr: { class: 'fa fa-' + ko.unwrap(icon) }"></i>
      </button> 
</span>
<h4>Comments</h4>
<div data-bind="css: { 'open': toolbar[4].state, 'closed': !toolbar[4].state() }">
Support requests, bug reports, and off-topic comments will be deleted without warning.

Please do post corrections and additional information/pointers for this article below. We aim to move corrections into our documentation as quickly as possible. Be aware that your comments may take some time to appear.

If you need specific help with your account, please contact our support team.
</div>
```